How to fetch data from 5-6 levels of nested Dictionary?
I need to fetch data from nested Dictionary IN C#. My Dictionary is like this:
static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>> allOffset = new();

I need to fetch data as mentioned below:

Get all values without passing any key
Get all values by passing only partial keys

Example data,
{
(2024,("B1",("C1",("E1","Employee1")))),
(2024,("B1",("C1",("E2","Employee2"))))
}

Expected Outputs:

Using keys 2024 or 2024, B1, C1


I should get both records


Using keys 2024, B1, C1, E1


I should get only first record


If I do not pass any keys


Then I should get both records

If this is not feasible with nested dictionary then I am open for any other type of collection.
I have reviewed how to fetch data from nested Dictionary in c# but it contains only two levels and not sure how to implement for 4/5/6 nested levels.
Update:
Adding code sample to prepare dummy data.
public void FillDumyData()
{
    for (int i = 2022;i<=2024;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 1;k<=7; k++)
            {
                EmployeeData.Add(i, j.ToString(), k.ToString(),$"{i}-{j}-{k}");
            }

        }
    }
}


2024 and the other keys are not unique so dictionary wont work since the key needs to be unique

Can you provide a bit more context about your data model? What are "C1", "B1" etc with respect to employees? Are you trying to do indexing?

Maybe a Dictionary<(int, string, string, string), string> would work for you, i.e. a composite key.

Put that data in a database and use the filtering, indexing features of that database?

@fubo, Representation may be wrong but if you will consider the hierarchy the top level dictionary will have only 1 record of 2024. I have written it just for ease of an example.

@KlausGütter, composite key can work for case 2 and 3 bot not for case 1 where i need data with partial key

Do these partial keys have their "wildcards" only at the end? Then a SortedDictionary might be a suitable data structure.

Where does this data come from? It's quite possible the best answer is to not use 3 levels of nested dictionaries to begin with. The data you posted looks a lot like a DataTable, XML data, JObject or list of objects that was converted into nested dictionaries. It would be easier and faster to query the original form.

It is feasible, but if the level you want to query is dynamic, you have to use non-generic types for input and output:
static object? Search(IDictionary d, params object[] keys)
{
    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        var v = d[key]; // get inner dict recursively
        if (v is IDictionary d2)
            d = d2;
        else
            return v; // single value
    }

    return FlattenDictionary(d); // value collection

    // the return type can be IEnumerable<string>
    static IEnumerable FlattenDictionary(IDictionary d)
    {
        foreach (var v in d.Values)
        {
            if (v is IDictionary d2)
            {
                // get the value of the inner-most dict recursively 
                foreach (var v2 in FlattenDictionary(d2))
                    yield return v2;
            }
            else
                yield return v;
        }
    }
}


Thank you @shingo. This looks promising. I am testing out your solution and will mark as accepted once i am done with my testing.

I would suggest using a custom class with tags field to search. this approach is extendable for any level required.
static List<MySearchableItem> items = [new MySearchableItem { 

EmployeeName = "Employee1", Code = "E2", Tags = ["2024", "B1", "C1", "E1", "Employee1"] },
new MySearchableItem { EmployeeName = "Employee2", Code = "E1", Tags = ["2024", "B1", "C1", "E2", "Employee2"] }];
public static List<MySearchableItem> Search(params string[] searchStrings)
{
    return items.Where(i => searchStrings.All(s => i.Tags.Contains(s))).ToList();
}
 public class MySearchableItem
 {
     public string EmployeeName { get; set; } = default!;
     public string Code { get; set; } = default!;

     public List<string> Tags { get; set; } = [];
 }


Smart one. but in real use for me, I am having a third party class as value. And would not prefer to alter that by adding inheriting that into a new class with Tag property. buy yes this can be a solution in general.
